# Error when trying to detect if error has shown on website selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriverwait

I'm testing if a website has thrown an error and I myself get an error to see if this happens.
So far I am just seeing if a button is clickable so if the button is not clickable/not displayed, then the program is okay to proceed. But if an error is there I need to return a value.

```
try:
    dismissBtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Dismiss this error']")))
    print("Reg Error Button is clickable")
finally:
    print("No error")
```

The error is below

```
dismissBtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Dismiss this error']")))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

HTML Code is below

```
<div id="6823e3dd-d694-4a3e-99ae-6c074e3af73d" class="unite-error-panel errorPanel unite-component">
    <span class="unite-h1-no-image">An error occurred.</span>
      <ul>
      
        <li>We are unable to connect to our servers right now. Please try again later.</li>
      
      </ul>
    <div id="8977e4fa-bb61-4a51-8b56-5e051b7f95d1" class="unite-error-code" style="display: none;"> {"code":"GENERIC","httpStatus":0}</div>
    <div id="0b57d2f0-a8c4-4b7e-8095-ae09054cb053" class="unite-error-close">
      <input type="button" value="Dismiss this error">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there another way I can go around this?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant text based HTML of the element would have helped us to analyze if the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you are using identifies the desired element uniquely. Assuming the element is uniquely identified, as it is a **error** message:

- It can be within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)
- It may need some delta time to appear within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

Perhaps increasing the waiting time from **2** seconds to **5** seconds will solve the issue.

Comment: I've updated the html code if you would like to take a look. The error doesn't always show which is good, but when it does show I would like the program to handle it.